# Please allow users to flag deleted questions for moderator attention

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, deleted-questions

Deleted questions lack the "flag" button, preventing us from flagging them for moderator attention. This would be useful if someone feels a question was unjustly deleted, and would like a moderator to look into it.

Comment: This is only usable for 10k+ users.

I'd rather be able to comment on deleted posts/questions (with sufficient rights)

Comment: @Ivo: well, under-10k users could still use this to flag (or comment on, as you suggest) their own deleted posts.  either way i think both suggestions could be useful.

Comment: Don't locked questions lack that link too?

Comment: @json: Not anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good idea, but it's kind of tricky because 99% of our queries include the clause `where DeletionDate is null` -- and turning that off for flags means we'd then see flags on *all* deleted posts for all time.

The general rule is that you don't care about deleted posts in the typical case, so we'd have to think that through.

How common is it to need to flag a deleted post, I wonder?

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the response.

Comment: When it's not deleted enough.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with quack's comment that it could be useful for users to flag one of their questions that was deleted.

I personally would only delete a question if we don't want it to be visible anymore, else I would simply close it. I can't imagine a case where I would be doing this unjustly.

Deleting should be a last resort solution, so if it has been done that question is likely to be unsalvageable and shouldn't be undeleted.

Comment: 10K users can vote to delete questions. We are all fallible, and may vote to delete something that we shouldn't. This would allow other [10K] users to flag for a moderator, who may choose to undelete and even lock the post to prevent further activity.

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224867/what-programming-language-do-you-wish-would-quietly-retire. The question was undeleted by Atwood, and then redeleted by 10K users. I would like to flag this and ask a mod to undelete and lock it.

Comment: i expect a lot more SO questions are deleted by user votes; on SU that's fairly uncommon.

Comment: Probably because I became a mod just before hitting 10k, that I never realized that

Comment: @quack: Right now, the 30-question most-recently-deleted list on SO goes back 15 hours.